# Show total number of rows in pouchdb

Tags: pouchdb

I have some data in the pouchdb, I want to show the total rows in pouchdb, how can I do it?

```
angular.module("pouchapp", ["ui.router"])

.run(function($pouchDB) {
    $pouchDB.setDatabase("dbinfo");
    //console.log($pouchDB.length); //show total rows in pouchdb   
});

.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", function($rootScope, $q) {
    var database;

    this.setDatabase = function(databaseName) {
        database = new PouchDB(databaseName);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using promises and the `allDocs` function, getting the number of documents could look like this in Typescript. I'm assuming the `$pouchDB` variable holds your PouchDB.

```
$pouchDB.allDocs().then(entries => console.log(entries.rows.length));
```

A plain javascript solution with callbacks could look like this:

```
$pouchDB.allDocs(function(err, response) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(response.rows.length);
});
```

---

Note: See the [docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) for more information about the `allDocs` function.

And make sure to call the `allDocs` function with the `include_docs` parameter if you actually want to get the documents. By default, you will only get the `_id` and `_rev` properties, not the whole document.

Actually fetching all documents could look like this:

```
$pouchDB.allDocs({
  include_docs: true
}).then(entries => console.log(entries));
```

Comment: but in angularjs they decline to accept .then, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Glad it helped :) Feel free to [vote up and accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Comment: It's probably better to use $pouchd.info().then(info => console.log(info.doc_count)), otherwise you're getting a list of all documents which is a lot of overhead that you don't need.

Comment: i am having 10000000+ rows taking so much long to execute query

Answer (score 11):

@Phonolog suggested `allDocs()` but I would recommend using `info()` as this has less overhead and will be faster.

```
$pouchDB.info().then(info => console.log(info.doc_count))
```